# How do I get css-loader and style-loader properly working to allow me to use my CSS file with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am setting up a simple React and Express application using Webpack and I have run into a problem where I am apparently not using my loaders correctly. I have however gone through the docs and I seemingly have them set up right. Does anyone have any idea why the loaders are not being recognized correctly?

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "jobhound",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Running-On-Fumes/jobhound.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Running-On-Fumes/jobhound/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Running-On-Fumes/jobhound#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^27.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.53.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

I have seemingly set up my webpack config correctly:
webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'src');
const OUT_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(SRC_DIR, 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: OUT_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader",
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  
};
```

I even imported it to my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/NavBar.css';

ReactDom.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App/>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('App'));
```

I am just trying to do a simple change in the CSS file to test it out:

```
.NavBar {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
NavBar.css:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .NavBar {
|     font-weight: bolder;
| }
    at eval (NavBar.css:1)
    at Object../client/src/css/NavBar.css (bundle.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:424)
    at eval (index.js:6)
    at Object../client/src/index.js (bundle.js:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:424)
    at bundle.js:488
    at bundle.js:490
```

Here is my file tree just in case...
[image]

Comment: Is your problem existing?

Comment: Yes the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The `module.exports.resolve.extensions` property in your webpack.config only has `.js` and `.jsx`. Try adding `.css` as well.

Comment: Tried it and am still receiving the same error. Thank you though!